# How can I add a new element to each line of a file

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a file with this content:

```
CHROM_POS
chr10_100009635
chr10_100187980
chr10_100229692
chr10_100267650
chr10_100269675
chr10_100279430
chr10_100285899
```

I want to add new content to this file like:

```
chrX-1, chrX
```

wherein X represent the above number
So it should be

```
chr10_100285898 chr10_100285899
```

Comment: Is this new content supposed to be appended to the file, so you end up with 9 lines instead of 8? If not, what? How are we to determine `X`? What have _you_ tried already? It's much easier for us to build on something you've already tried rather than start from scratch

Comment: Using your template notation, the example appears to be `chrX-1, chrX`. Is this correct?

Comment: My guess is that because of the `+1` you will need a language such as `awk` or another programming language. If not for the `+1` / `-1` then `sed` would have been powerful enough. However, we may be surprised that a Perl regexp can do it.

Comment: Yes, it should be ChrX-1, ChrX. I don't want to append to any file but just rewrite this one

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect the actual request rather than leaving the clarification in a comment.

Answer (score 6):

A Perl solution:

```
perl -p -e 's;([^_]+)_(\d+);"$1_" . ($2 - 1) . " $1_$2";e'
```

The `-p` flag loops over all lines, `-e` gives the script as an argument. The `([^_]+)` captures what comes before `_` into `$1`, (\d+)`captures the digits into`$2`, the` e` modifier to the replacement enables expressions.

Give your input file as an argument or just as standard input.

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`:

```bsh
awk -F _ 'NR > 1 { $0 = sprintf("%s_%d, %s_%d", $1, $2-1, $1, $2) }; 1' file
```

or slightly shorter,

```bsh
awk -F _ 'NR > 1 { $0 = sprintf("%s_%d, %s", $1, $2-1, $0) }; 1' file
```

This assumes that you want to leave the first line intact and that you want a comma between the resulting columns. Remove the comma from the `sprintf()` format string if you want no comma.

The code does not do anything with the first line, but rewrites all other lines using `sprintf()` according to a `chrX_(N-1), chrX_N` pattern, which seems to be what you're asking for.

The bits of the original line, i.e. the chromosome name and the genomic location on the chromosome, are picked out by treating the data as two `_`-delimited fields.  The chromosome name is therefore read into `$1` and the position into `$2`.

The `1` at the very end of the `awk` code causes the data, modified or not, to be outputted.

Output given your example data:

```
CHROM_POS
chr10_100009634, chr10_100009635
chr10_100187979, chr10_100187980
chr10_100229691, chr10_100229692
chr10_100267649, chr10_100267650
chr10_100269674, chr10_100269675
chr10_100279429, chr10_100279430
chr10_100285898, chr10_100285899
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked and I understand the explanation.

Comment: I also have one more doubt. If I want to specifically get the output as chr10 100009634 100009635, should I use the awk command?

Comment: @priyanka You really should have said in the question what format you wanted the output to be in. You shouldn't ask for something when you want something else. However, in this case it's just a matter of using `sprintf("%s %d %d", $1, $2-1, $2)` in assignment to `$0` in the code.  With that, it ought to be fairly easy for you to see how to change the format in whatever way you need.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for that. But thank you for taking time and explaining me the answer.

Comment: In case the number has leading zeros: `sprintf("%s_%0*d, %s", $1, length($2), $2-1, $0)`

Comment: @DavidFoerster These numbers are likely positions on a chromosome. As such, they should not be zero-padded.

Answer (score 0):

Awk-based solution:

```
awk -F '_' -v OFS=, 'NR>1{ $0 = $1 FS $2-1 OFS $0 }1' file
```

---

Results:-

```
CHROM_POS
chr10_100009634,chr10_100009635
chr10_100187979,chr10_100187980
chr10_100229691,chr10_100229692
chr10_100267649,chr10_100267650
chr10_100269674,chr10_100269675
chr10_100279429,chr10_100279430
chr10_100285898,chr10_100285899
```

---

Other approaches:

[perl]

```
perl -lsne '
  print $.>1 ? s/(\d+)$/$1-1/re : (), $_;
' -- -,=, file
```

---

[Python3]

```
python3 -c 'import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  for nr,_ in enumerate(f,1):
    _ = _.rstrip("\n")
    if nr > 1:
      p = _.find("_") + 1
      _ = _[:p] + f"{int(_[p:])-1}," + _
    print(_)
' file
```

---

[GNU dc] the RPN calculator

```
< file \
sed 's/^/[/;1s/$/]/;1!s/_/&]/' |
dc ​-e "
[q]sq
[rdnrd1-n44anrnpc]sp
[?z0=q lpx z0=?]s?
?pc l?x
"
```

---

[GNU sed]

```
sed -Ee '1b
  h
  s/^[^_]*_//
  s/$/\n9876543210/;tdecr
  :decr
  s/([^0])\n.*\1(.).*/\2/;tdone
  s/([^0])(0+\n.*\1(.))/\3_\2/
  :loop
    s/_0(0*\n)/9_\1/
  tloop
  s/_.*//
  :done
  G
  s/.*\n([^_]*_)/\1&/
  y/\n/,/
' file
```